# Double Equals in Strings vs. Arrays (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, equals

Why does the **code snippet 1 evaluate to true** while **code snippet 2 print false** considering both **Strings and Arrays are objects**?

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
System.out.println (s1 == s2);
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
int [] arr = {0,1,2};
int [] arr2 = {0,1,2};
System.out.println (arr == arr2);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you are talking about Java?

Comment: @Timo, yes I am referring to Java.

Comment: String **cache** is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

They are both objects, **but Java reuses objects for strings** where it makes sense.

> [...] Java String Pool — the special memory region where Strings are stored by the JVM.
>
> Thanks to the immutability of Strings in Java, the JVM can optimize
> the amount of memory allocated for them by storing only one copy of
> each literal String in the pool. This process is called interning.
>
> When we create a String variable and assign a value to it, the JVM
> searches the pool for a String of equal value.
>
> If found, the Java compiler will simply return a reference to its
> memory address, without allocating additional memory.
>
> If not found, it’ll be added to the pool (interned) and its reference
> will be returned.

[Source](http://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool)

Comment: thank you. So, it turns out that String is an exception!

Comment: @user9249390 Not only `String`, even `Integer` (as long as value is between `-128` and `127` or something like that) is drawn from a cache. Note that I'm talking about the object `Integer`, not the primitive `int`.